# C++ vector on arduino takes up massive RAM footprint

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, arduino, ram

Couldn't find a solution to this anywhere. Hoping to become more enlightened on this subject.

I wanted to use a dynamic array of sorts for an arduino project. I came across a library for using vectors on the arduino platform [here](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus). I used a function to monitor free RAM on the arduino that I found [here](http://www.controllerprojects.com/2011/05/23/determining-sram-usage-on-arduino/).

Here is an example of my code:

```
Serial.print("Starting RAM: ");
Serial.println(freeRam());
Serial.println();

vector<int> intVector;

Serial.print("Remaining RAM after intVector declaration: ");
Serial.println(freeRam());
Serial.println();

vector<char> charVector;

Serial.print("Remaining RAM after charVector declaration: ");
Serial.println(freeRam());
Serial.println();


Serial.print("sizeof(intVector) = ");
Serial.println(sizeof(intVector));
Serial.print("sizeof(charVector) = ");
Serial.println(sizeof(charVector));
```

And here's the output:

```
Starting RAM: 1684

Remaining RAM after intVector declaration: 1618

Remaining RAM after charVector declaration: 1584

sizeof(intVector) = 7
sizeof(charVector) = 7
```

It seems that the intVector allocation took up a 66 byte chunk of the RAM. It appears the vector allots 32*2 + 2 = 66 bytes of memory for this. Likewise, the charVector allocation took up 34 bytes (32*1 + 2). It seems this pattern of allocating 32*`sizeof(type)` + change exists for other data types (such as char, float, etc). Note that `sizeof(int) = 2` on arduino.

My problem is that the objects I would like to populate these vectors with are anywhere from 10-20 bytes large. With only 2 kB of RAM available on the ATMega328, I won't be able to run my program as it's currently designed. For an object `segment` with `sizeof(segment) = 16`, a vector eats up a 522-byte block of RAM.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the vector allocate 32 * sizeof(type) bytes of RAM when the size of the vector is only 7 bytes, despite its type?
2. Is there a better way to use a sort of dynamic array on the arduino platform?
3. Are there memory management techniques that may allow me to use vectors?

Thanks, and sorry in advance if this question is a duplicate!

EDIT:

It seems that the vector is initialized with a capacity of 32.

```
intVector.capacity() = 32;
```

Attempting to use either

```
intVector.reserve(1); // or
intVector.resize(1);
```

does not alter the capacity of the vector.

Comment: Do you have C++11? What happens if you run `vector.shrink_to_fit`? And if you add 32 elements to your vectors, does it increase memory usage?

Comment: I do not have C++11. I'll look into seeing if I can implement that on arduino. Thanks for the recommendation - I hope it works.

Comment: You might try looking at std::deque.

Answer (score 5):

A vector allocates more space at a time than it needs, for efficiency - you wouldn't want it reallocating every time you tried to insert a single item. It's quite possible that it initializes with a capacity of 32 items even though it's still empty.

Try printing out `vec.capacity()` to find out how many elements it's reserved space for.

A vector is the most space efficient of the standard containers, it should use only the amount required for each element plus some constant overhead.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the quick reply. vec.capacity() = 32. From other examples I've seen online, it doesn't seem like this is standard for c++ vectors. I may have to hack into the library I downloaded to see if I can change this setting.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look through that `vector` implementation shows that it always reserves an extra `__UCLIBCXX_STL_BUFFER_SIZE__` bytes of memory. That preprocessor symbol is defined as `32` in `system_configuration.h`.

So default constructing a `vector` always takes up 32 bytes plus whatever overhead the `vector` itself has to keep track of allocated memory, size, capacity etc.

You could try changing the preprocessor definition in `system_configuration.h` to

```
#define __UCLIBCXX_STL_BUFFER_SIZE__ 0
```

but this might break the code if there's anything that depends on this space always being allocated.

Comment: Or perhaps some middle ground would be safer, like 8

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, std::vector always allocates some memory ahead of time in order to prevent reallocating every time you insert. Asking the system for more memory is an expensive process, which you'd want to avoid as much as possible.

**Write a custom allocator.** The allocator is an optional template argument to std::vector, and with it you can redefine how it gets memory (e.g. make it preallocate a smaller amount, reallocate on every insert, etc.). For more information on this, you can check out Nicolai Josuttis's [website](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) on the STL. There is a free chapter that covers allocators (the header "Supplementary Chapter (PDF)" in the side bar, and there is also [sample code](http://www.cppstdlib.com/code/alloc/myalloc11.cpp.html).

Comment: The allocator does not define how much reserve memory should be allocated.  The Vector pre-allocates 32 entries.